# Creating a time picker in android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I want to create a time picker like shown in 1st image. I tried with timepicker mode as spinner but it is not available on API<21. I tried with number picker,using  layout height as match parent (image 3) and wrap content(image 2) but can`t get desired result.

[image][image][image]

Comment: why are your creating time picker from the ground when lots of great libraries already done that and if you really want to do what are your doing please provide some code and layout for better understanding

Comment: i think this can be Done with RecyclerView with pagerSnapHelper .. Give it a try ..

Comment: Looks like it can solve the issue, But I think i then i have to use 2 recyclerviews. Also how can i add endless scroll like number picker or time picker spinner